# What is the strongest glue to secure a loose shower head?

Tags: plumbing, shower, tile

I think whoever installed the plumbing used CPVS and didn't even secure the shower head so it's loose. I don't want to open up the tiled wall so I'm going to spray some Great Stuff foam in the hole and use some kind of glue around the pipe. What would you recommend? I thought about grout but I think that would just crumble after a while. Maybe some sort of cement? I can cut around the pipe to add more room for any kind of adhesive/cement.

Comment: The foam itself will do the job. You can't glue to foam anyway, and you wouldn't want to glue to the tile.

Comment: FYI, you have what's known as an XY question here--you've asked about a proposed solution instead of asking *for* a good solution. You might revise to just ask how to solve the problem. As it is you probably won't earn many reputation credits. [Take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) if what I just said makes no sense. :)

Comment: To readers, this isn't a product recommendation question. It can be interpreted to be about adhesive *types*, not brand names.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture of the shower head and its potential mounting point would be really helpful.

Comment: is there room under the edifice flange to hide a hose clamp? i fixed a wobbly one like that a while back...

Comment: Looks like you were right Isherwood! The foam alone did the job. Thanks (sorry didn't know how to upload a picture)